# How to connect Trac Version 0.12 to SVN

Tags: svn, trac

In Trac 0.12 ,trac-admin no longer asks questions related to repositories. So how can i connect the Trac system to the SVN and make it show the "Browse Source" tab in the GUI?

Thanks for any advices,
Sven

p.s: I used this tutorial for installing Trac and SVN: http://www.sohailriaz.com/how-to-install-subversion-with-trac-on-centos-5-x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**

Use Trac wiki, not 3-rd party blogs of unknown quality and related to obviously old versions (check date of blog-post)

**Face**

Starting with 0.12, Trac can handle more than one repository per environment. The pre-0.12 way of specifying the repository with the repository_dir and repository_type options in the [trac] section of trac.ini is still supported, but two new mechanisms allow including additional repositories into an environment.

See further details in [Repository Administration](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.12/TracRepositoryAdmin#Repositories) page

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I failed to find the place were to set the repository_dir (looked in section [svn] instead of [trac])